# How can I bottom & center-horizontally align a TextView on a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml

Based on this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lytContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scanButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/scan" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/authorship"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'd like to keep the Scan Button centered horizontally keeping the screen ratio, so it's always kept in the middle of the screen.

Next, I'd like to have the TextView centered on the bottom of the screen and centered too, like this:

[image: An example of how I want it to look like]

Seems like the property and value of `android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"` I have on the LinearLayout is stopping me from having it so, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Can you please attach ui image for a reference?

Comment: I already attached an image of how I'd like for it to look like on the post. Here's the link of the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JlEp.png

Comment: Do you want header also??

Comment: You mean the title of the view? The one it's censored in the screenshot? If so, I really would like it to be centered. If by header you mean a top title, that would work too, it'll look better :)

Comment: Well I give you code snippet without toolbar you customize it yourself!!

Comment: instead linear layout use Relative or ConstraintLayout layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code snippet here I hope this work for you as per your need...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:cornerRadius="10dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Scan Product"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />




    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```